# How to generate a string containing forward slash with regular expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the following Javascript to generate a String: `/abc/.source`.
By running this code in console, it will return `"abc"`.

Now I want to generate a string like `"abc/"`.

I tried `/abc\//.source` but it returns `"abc\/"`.

How can I achieve this WITHOUT using `var reg = new RegExp("abc/");reg.source`?

Comment: why would you ever inspect `regex.source`?

Comment: I'm carrying out some project that's sensitive to punctuations.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by generating a string by creating a regex and inspecting its `source` property.  The regex is created with a string, so if you have the string already, what is the `source` property lookup going to buy you?

Comment: I don't think what you're asking for is possible, and I definitely feel like you're abusing regex for something it wasn't meant for.

Comment: The point is that it returns a string without using quotation marks.

Comment: This is starting to sound a little nefarious

Comment: Oh man take it easy! This is just for a course project I'm doing...

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but  would guess it should be `\\/`

Comment: Thanks for answering but it doesn't work

Comment: +1 for your comment, and because your name is "Dvorak" @JanDvorak `^^`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the *source* property:

> Let S be a String in the form of a Pattern equivalent to P, in which
>   certain characters are escaped as described below. S may or may not be
>   identical to P or pattern; however, the internal procedure that would
>   result from evaluating S as a Pattern must behave identically to the
>   internal procedure given by the constructed object's [[Match]]
>   internal property.

[15.10.4.1 new RegExp(pattern, flags)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.4.1)

In other words, the source value must be able to be used as the string in a regular expression constructor:

```
var re = new RegExp( s.source );
```

Where the resulting expression must behave the same as the original when used in *match*.

So given that to match 'abc/' the required pattern is `abc\/` then `/abc\//.source` must be `abc\/`.

And BTW:

```
(new RegExp('abc/')).source == 'abc\/';
```